# Set jQuery Datepicker value restricted to last month only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this script for selecting date.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: "-5M",
            maxDate: "-1M",   
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
    function Image13_onclick() {
    }
</script>
```

this allows me to select any date from past five months. I want just one month for the user to select and that should be previous
 month. For example if current month is March then datepicker should only have Feb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.
So you only need to calculate the right min date and max date. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2GVn/)

```
$(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var maxDate = "-" + date.getDate() + "D";
        var minDate = "-1M " + "-" + (date.getDate() - 1) + "D";;
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: minDate,
            maxDate: maxDate,   
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: Its really Helpful. Thanks a lot .@Alex Ou